# Can MSBuild in the Framework\v4.0.30319 folder be used to build 3.5 projects?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have many different projects that I use nAnt to build.  Inside of nAnt, I use MSBuild.  My question is, can I set the path of where to find MSBuild to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and have it build both the 3.5 projects and the 4.5 projects or do I have to use the MSBuild specifically for 3.5 projects?  I need to make sure the 3.5 projects stay and only are compiled in 3.5 and not in 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to build .NET 3.5 projects with no problems using MSBuild from .NET 4.5.